# Do my children have French nationality?

Tags: citizenship, french-citizens

I am French and have been living in the UK for a long time with my British husband.

We have adopted twin boys (full adoption) 20 years ago when they were 7 months old (now 21).

Do they automatically take the French nationality?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic? No. Especially since you were living abroad. But your children may have the right to ask for it. [This page](https://ci.ambafrance.org/Acquisition-de-la-nationalite-1624) says, among other things, that the France residency requirement is waived if the French parent doesn't reside in France. On the other hand, it mentions that an *exequatur* is required for the adoption to be recognized in France, if it was done abroad. Which I suppose is your case: if you adopted the children in the UK, you'll need to have this adoption legally recognized at the French Consulate.

Once this is done, since they're adults, **they** will have to talk to the French Consulate. They're the only ones now who can ask for the French citizenship.

Comment: The page you've linked to concerns simple adoption, while the question concerns full adoption *(adoption plénière* in French).

Comment: "Un enfant adopté sous la forme plénière par un Français est français par filiation." https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F3070